# How to show a custom 404 error page when using a Lambda@Edge frunction serving a website from Cloudfront to a private S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-serverless

I am using the [standard-redirects-for-cloudfront](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:621073008195:applications~standard-redirects-for-cloudfront) Lambda@Edge function that handles

> "internal" redirects from /foo/ to /foo/index.html and "external"
>   redirects from /foo/index.html to /foo/.

```
'use strict';

/*
  Copyright 2017 DigitalSailors e.K.
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
*/

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

  let prefixPath; // needed for 2nd condition

  if (request.uri.match('.+/$')) {
    request.uri += 'index.html';
    callback(null, request);
  } else if (prefixPath = request.uri.match('(.+)/index.html')) {
    const response = {
      status: '301',
      statusDescription: 'Found',
      headers: {
        location: [{
          key: 'Location', value: prefixPath[1] + '/',
        }],
      }
    };
    callback(null, response);
  } else if (request.uri.match('/[^/.]+$')) {
    const response = {
      status: '301',
      statusDescription: 'Found',
      headers: {
        location: [{
          key: 'Location', value: request.uri + '/',
        }],
      }
    };
    callback(null, response);
  } else {
    callback(null, request);
  }
}
```

I am having problems serving a custom error page.

Currently I have in my S3 bucket the object */404.html* (also configured as the error page of the S3 static website which shouldn't be requested anyway because it should be Cloudfront responsability).

In Cloudfront I've set up */404.html* as the custom error page for 404 status.

How should I set it up to return the error page?

```
marcanuy@scarone:~/Development/website$ curl -I https://example.com/wrong-page
HTTP/2 301                                                                                                                            
server: CloudFront                                                                                                                    
location: /wrong-page/                                                                                                                
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront                                                                                                         

marcanuy@scarone:~/Development/website$ curl -I https://example.com/wrong-page.html
HTTP/2 403
content-type: application/xml
server: AmazonS3
x-cache: Error from cloudfront

marcanuy@scarone:~/Development/website$ curl -I https://example.com/404
HTTP/2 301
server: CloudFront
location: /404/
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront

marcanuy@scarone:~/Development/website$ curl -I https://example.com/404.html
HTTP/2 200
content-type: text/html
last-modified: Fri, 03 Aug 2018 03:38:19 GMT
etag: "4ecbbfd9d1eb384afc897df3f29a8865"
accept-ranges: bytes
server: AmazonS3
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error page is not being returned because above function is being executed when CloudFront fetches the custom error page.

To ensure the function is not executed while requesting a custom error page from S3 bucket, custom error page can be served from a different cache behavior in which no Lambda function is configured.

For example, a cache behavior with path pattern **/error-pages/*** can be configured without any Lambda and **/error-pages/404.html** can be set up for custom error page on 404 status code from the origin.